# creating a circle of bars with HTML5 canvas, but the space between bars is uneven

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to create a circular progressbar(though it wouldn't be a bar anymore, would it?). Around this cricle there are thin bars perpendicular to the circle. Now the problem is, my code doesn't generate there bars in an even spacing. Here's the code and an image of the result:
[image: uneven perpendicular lines to the circle]

```
function MH5PB(canvasId,            //the id of the canvas to draw the pb on
                value,              //a float value, representing the progress(ex: 0.3444)
                background,         //the background color of the pb(ex: "#ffffff")
                circleBackground,   //the background color of the bars in the circles
                integerColor,       //the color of the outer circle(or the int circle)
                floatColor          //the color of the inner circle(or the float circle)
                )
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
    var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
    var radius = Math.min(canvasWidth, canvasHeight) / 2;
    var numberOfBars = 72;
    var barThickness = 2;

    //margin from the borders, and also the space between the two circles
    var margin = parseInt(radius / 12.5) >= 2 ? parseInt(radius / 12.5) : 2; 

    //the thickness of the int circle and the float circle
    var circleThickness = parseInt((radius / 5) * 2);

    //the outer radius of the int circle
    var intOuterRadius = radius - margin;
    //the inner radius of the int circle
    var intInnerRadius = radius - margin - circleThickness;

    //the outer radius of the float circle
    var floatOuterRadius = intOuterRadius - margin - circleThickness;
    //the inner radius of the float circle
    var floatInnerRadius = floatOuterRadius - circleThickness;

    //draw a bar, each degreeStep degrees
    var intCircleDegreeStep = 5;
                                    // ((2 * Math.PI * intOuterRadius) / (barThickness + 10)) //
                                    //  this area is the total number of required bars  //
                                    //  to fill the intCircle.1px space between each bar//
    var floatCircleDegreeStep = 360 / ((2 * Math.PI * floatOuterRadius) / (barThickness + 10));        

    context.lineWidth = barThickness;
    context.strokeStyle = circleBackground;
    //draw the bg of the outer circle
    for(i = 90; i < 450; i+=intCircleDegreeStep)
    {
        //since we want to start from top, and move cw, we have to map the degree
        //in the loop
        cxOuter = Math.floor(intOuterRadius * Math.cos(i) + radius);
        cyOuter = Math.floor(intOuterRadius * Math.sin(i) + radius);
        cxInner = Math.floor(intInnerRadius * Math.cos(i) + radius);
        cyInner = Math.floor(intInnerRadius * Math.sin(i) + radius);
        context.moveTo(cxOuter, cyOuter);
        context.lineTo(cxInner, cyInner);
        context.stroke();
    }
}
```

EDIT: Oh, and also the lines aren't anti-aliased. Do you know why?
I should also explain that this progressbar consists of two parts. An outer circle (visible in the provided image) and an inner circle. The outer circle is the amount of the integer part of the percentage (i.e. 45 in 45.98%) and the inner circle is the amount of the not integer part of the percentage (i.e. 98 in 45.98%). Hence you now know what intCircle and floatCircle are :)

Comment: Just a small guess here: Your number of bars might not be liked by the thing, so it's condensing them to produce a good circle? Speculation

Comment: Thanks for your interest Ian. Well, I'm not sure. I suspect that it's got something to do with the sine and cosine functions, you know. Since they produce a double value, the amount added to the next coordinates is uneven. But I don't know how to fix it :D And by the way, thanks for the edit ;)

Comment: I've never drawn anything in JS before, so I'd sadly be of no help here. Take an upvote, though. :)

Comment: Appreciate it buddy :).

Comment: you do not need `parseInt` when you calculate `margin`. Same with `circleThickness`. Please set up a sample on jsfiddle or something similar.

Comment: OK. I'm not an expert in js, but wouldn't radius / 12.5 result in a floating point value??

Comment: you can use `Math.round` to convert it to integer.

Comment: That could also do it :-D. Here's the jsfiddle. I'm new to jsfiddle, but it doesn't work there! http://jsfiddle.net/caJfA/

Comment: You are feeding degrees to `Math.sin` and `Math.cos`. These functions are working with radians.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f8F7q/ Keep everything in floating point. Iterate around the circle by fractions of *pi* not integer degrees.

Comment: Thank you all guys, that was exactly the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears you are passing degrees to Math.sin and Math.cos.  These functions expect radians.  For example,

```
// i degrees to radians.
Math.sin(i * (Math.PI / 180));
```

Comment: This, plus *all* the rounding/truncation stuff needs to go.

Comment: Oh my God! Shame on me for neglecting that. Thanks a lot, it worked. but still the anti-aliasing thing is a problem. Since canvas has it by default, do you know why it doesn't work in this case?

Comment: @MNVOH get rid of all your integer conversions and rounding.  See [the fiddle I made from yours](http://jsfiddle.net/f8F7q/).

Comment: @MNVOH, two things: 1) Add a call to context.beginPath() before your context.moveTo() - this should clear up the anti-aliasing issue.  2) Depending upon how you call your function you might need to clear the context with context.clearRect(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight) after acquiring the context and determining the dimensions.

Comment: Thanks a gazillion times veritasetratio, that solved the aliasing problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the way the lines are close and then far apart in a regular pattern (five close areas in your example) that gives you a good indication that it's related to your trig functions.  You can almost see the sine wave in the pattern.

In any case, your math for drawing the rays has some errors.  Try this simplified example:

```
function MH5PB(canvasId,            //the id of the canvas to draw the pb on
                value,              //a float value, representing the progress(ex: 0.3444)
                background,         //the background color of the pb(ex: "#ffffff")
                circleBackground,   //the background color of the bars in the circles
                integerColor,       //the color of the outer circle(or the int circle)
                floatColor          //the color of the inner circle(or the float circle)
                )
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById(canvasId);
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var barThickness = 2;

    context.lineWidth = barThickness;
    context.strokeStyle = circleBackground;


    var innerRadius = 30;
    var outerRadius = 80;
    var center = { x:50, y:50 };
    var percentDone = 60;
    var angleOfPercentDone = percentDone * 360 / 100;

    //rotate everything -90 degrees
    angleOfPercentDone -= 90;
    for(var angle = -90; angle < angleOfPercentDone; angle +=5)
    {
        //convert to radians
        var rad = angle * Math.PI/180;
        var c = Math.cos(rad);
        var s = Math.sin(rad);
        var innerPointX = center.x + (innerRadius * c);
        var innerPointY = center.y + (innerRadius * s);
        var outerPointX = center.x + (outerRadius * c);
        var outerPointY = center.x + (outerRadius * s);
        context.moveTo(innerPointX, innerPointY);
        context.lineTo(outerPointX, outerPointY);
        context.stroke();
    }
}
```

View the fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/DXwrc/